# gridview batch edit form loss the values in serverside validation devexpress

Tags: devexpress

I am using aspxgridview in that i am using batch edit.

my condition if the user enter duplicate row value,i am using some condition to check the duplicate value while inserting. At the moment popwill show like "SKU Master Name already exist"

after that i lost all my values in the text what i am typed.

can any one resolve my issue.

first screen short

[image]

after check dulicate I lost my values what i typed

[image]

Comment: You want to Change Default java error popup right @vinoth

Comment: no i don't want to change the popup error. I want to get my values what i typed in the textboxes @jose

Answer (score 0):

In this post you can check which events are triggered during batch update at server side and afterwards at client side. You can get access to your values from a function called by the OnBatchUpdate event (define it in your aspx code), store them in a session and load them back even at save failure. The values seem to be retained until next reload

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T114462